# Calculating Variance between two days in a column

Tags: sql-server, average, moving-average, variance

I have this table below:

```
Fruit|  date    |  profit | Rolling_Avg
Apple|2014-01-16|   5.61  | 0.80
Apple|2014-01-17|   3.12  | 1.25
Apple|2014-01-18|   2.20  | 1.56
Apple|2014-01-19|   3.28  | 2.03
Apple|2014-01-20|   7.59  | 3.11
Apple|2014-01-21|   3.72  | 3.65
Apple|2014-01-22|   1.11  | 3.80
Apple|2014-01-23|   5.07  | 3.73
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the variance by dates in increments of 1 so for example the returned table would be like:

```
Fruit|  date    |  profit | Rolling_Avg| Variance %
Apple|2014-01-16|   5.61  | 0.80       |  
Apple|2014-01-17|   3.12  | 1.25       |-0.443850267
Apple|2014-01-18|   2.20  | 1.56       |-0.294871795
Apple|2014-01-19|   3.28  | 2.03       | 0.490909091
Apple|2014-01-20|   7.59  | 3.11       | 1.31402439
Apple|2014-01-21|   3.72  | 3.65       |-0.509881423
Apple|2014-01-22|   1.11  | 3.80       |-0.701612903
Apple|2014-01-23|   5.07  | 3.73       | 3.567567568
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

I suppose if the dates were headers instead of rows it would be easier to calculate variance % as

```
sum(([2014-01-17] - [2014-01-16])/[2014-01-16])) as [variance %]
```

but again not entirely sure this is the most efficient way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

Below is the Query which might give you the desired result.

**Query**

```
select fruit,vdate,profit,rolling_avg,
    LAG(profit,1,0) over(order by day(vdate)) as previousprofit,
    ((profit-LAG(profit) over(order by day(vdate)))/LAG(profit) over(order by day(vdate))) as variance_percent
from variance
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/WZKD96754)

Comment: You Sir, are a Legend. Thank you, this works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating the "variance" -- which has a specific definition in statistics -- but the "difference".  For this, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (rolling_avg - 
        lag(rolling_avg) over (order by date)
       ) as diff
from t;
```

I would do the difference as "recent" - "previous".  You seem to be going the other way, so just reverse the order of the operands.

Comment: Hi, not quite sure this answers my question. To clarify i am trying to achieve the returned example above for profit not moving average,. the answer below is is more what I am looking for. however need a more dynamic way of writing the dates to calculate the variances.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+ you can use lag as below:

```
Select *, (Profit - PrevProfit)/PrevProfit as [variance %] from (
    Select *, PrevProfit = lag(profit) over(partition by fruit order by [date]) 
    from #fruitdata
) a
```

Comment: Hi, this was what I initially had, however, is there a way to write it such that profit and preprofit does not have to be typed in manually?... as this current solution means  I would need to type in each date E.G.     `[2014-01-17] - [2014-01-16])/[2014-01-16]`  `[2014-01-18] - [2014-01-17])/[2014-01-17]` for multiple rows.

Comment: What you mean by "profit and preprofit does not have to be typed in"? Can you provide your sample data accordingly?

Comment: basically i am trying to achieve the **variance** column in the **2nd table** above. I have already used excel to show the desired answers to the variance column (e.g. profit **3.12** - **5.61**)/(pre profit **5.61**) = **-0.443850267**)  and placed it in my sample data that I want returned. Your script introduces a new column called `preprofit` which is not in my table of data

Comment: PrevProfit I am calculating based on your profit using lag function in subquery